# Is FxCop Dead? Can it be used with VS2015?

Tags: c#, coding-style, fxcop

I was browsing through Stack Overflow and Google for information about automatic coding style practice tools and found FxCop.

But I haven't found recent articles from Microsoft about FxCop. So, I was wondering if FxCop is dead.

Can FxCop be used with Visual Studio 2015? Will it work for enforcing C# design guidelines?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

FxCop functionality is integrated into Visual Studio 2012 and later versions with VS Code analysis. It covers all FxCop functionality with better integration.

Reference: [Code Analysis for Managed Code Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you this makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

From this [blog](http://michaelsync.net/2014/07/19/status-of-fxcop-code-analysis) (notice written by a Microsoft program manager):

> The old version IL-based FxCop/CA are dead but the new version of CA that based on source-code instead of IL will be in VS “14”.  (You can scroll down and see the reply from Alex Turner, the owner for Diagnostics in managed languages. )

So yes, it is dead, but replaced with something better. With CA you have an even better tool to do code analysis. Also, with Roslyn, it is quite easy to create your own analyzers.

Comment: Better is relative... There are benefits of doing IL analysis: 1) it is cross language 2) analyzes what is actually generated from source 3) includes code weaver modifications...

Answer (score 3):

No, not dead, just renamed or reincarnated.

Supplement to CarbineCoder's answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/36982685/257090

FxCop is now part of all editions of Visual Studio (Community, Pro, Enterprise)

There is a bit of confusion around it, because in the past, Microsoft upcharged for it, you had to buy Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate. As of 2012, as far as I recall, it was made free.

Answer (score 1):

FxCop rules have been re-implemented as source based Roslyn analyzers in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers) open source repo.

See [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers#recommended-version-of-analyzer-packages) for recommended version of NuGet package(s)/VSIX to use to get these analyzers to run during your building/editing experience in Visual Studio.

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview#roslyn-analyzers-vs-static-code-analysis) for further documentation.